# Elasticsearch is failing to run aggregations with huge data without any errors

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

Having a lot of data 160k+ documents in the index in a  cluster of 3 nodes, when running a query and aggregation with runtime mapping I got the hits only without even filtering the results.

Only with size 0 it works

Example:
A runtime mapping to calculate two fields
A query that will filter the documents to 2.7k
Aggregations

Structured as follows:

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "runtime_mappings": {-},
  "query": {-},
  "aggs": {-},
}
```

1. With size: 1

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [-]
  }
}
```

[Check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwZly.png)

2. With size: 0

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2731,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : [-]
}
```

[Check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sls8Y.png)

Is there anyone encountered such an issue ?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That looks like a bug. Is it reproducible with 8.x? Do you see anything in elasticsearch logs?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @imotov thanks, I can't upgrade to 8.x in this stage and no, I didn't see anything no errors and no logs ..

Comment: I suspect this bug is most likely related to caching. Try cleaning the cache or restarting the nodes to see if it will change this behavior.

Comment: I don't think it is related to caching, I think it is a bug, maybe when the query will take more than the timeout (in my case 30s) Elasticsearch will just return an incomplete result. I got that issue in two different environments.